# Nest thermostat e heat link replacing the old danfoss

Tags: wiring, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, central-heating, diy-vs-pro

[image][image]

I really need help with replacing this current danfoss thermostat with a new nest thermostat e heat hub. I'm in the UK.

Below is the new heatlink just need to know what wires I need to wire and what ones I need to isolate.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If this is the Nest E UK thermostat** (the same designation is used for completely different products in the USA. Nest's own documentation is not always clear which product is being referred to.)

On the Nest, there are terminals for **Common**, **NO** (normally open) and **NC** (normally closed).  In addition to these terminals you can also see the OT1 and OT2 terminals, which are used for OpenTherm.

Ignore OT1 and OT2.

Connect Danfoss **L** *Brown* to Nest **Common**

Danfoss **3 ON** *(black?) Sleeved Brown* to Nest **NO**.

Make sure that Neutral (*Grey sleeved blue*) and Earth (*green/yellow sleeve*) are tidied out of the way and cannot connect to anything.

Comment: This is perfect. worked a treat. Thank you so much. One of the easiest put answer to follow iv seen.